# unity3d: Camera does not follow the player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am fairly new in game development, I have a piece of code that makes camera move based on player's movement. 
player's movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

public float speed = 6f;
//to store movement
Vector3 movement;
Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
int floorMask;
float camRayLenghth = 100f;

//gets called regardless if the script is enabled or not
void Awake(){
    floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
    playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    //Input.ResetInputAxes ();
}

//unity calls automatically on every script and fire any physics object
void FixedUpdate(){
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
    Move (h, v);
    //Rotate ();

    Turning ();
}

void Move(float h, float v){
    movement.Set (h,0f,v);
    movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
}

void Turning (){
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit floorHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (camRay,out floorHit,camRayLenghth,floorMask)) {
        Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
        playerToMouse.y = 0f;
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);
        playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
    }
}
}
```

and here is the script attached to the main camera:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
// a target for camera to follow
public Transform player;

// how fast the camera moves
public float smoothing = 4f;

//the initial offset from the target
Vector3 offset;

void start(){
    //calculation of initial offset (distance) between player and camera
    offset = transform.position - player.position;
    Debug.Log ("offset is " + offset);
}

void FixedUpdate (){
    //updates the position of the camera based on the player's position and offset
    Vector3 playerCameraPosition = player.position + offset;

    //make an smooth transfer of location of camera using lerp
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, playerCameraPosition, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);            

}
}
```

but when I attach the script to my main camera, as soon as I play test the game camera starts to relocate and moves towards the ground even though the player hasn't moved yet. If I remove the script from the camera and make the camera the child of the player, as soon as I hit play, camera starts to rotate around the object.

Please give me some hints what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: did you attach the player to camera script via inspector?

Comment: yes, I attached it via inspecter

Answer (score 0):

The camera offset isn't being set because of the lower case on your start method.  This means the offset remains at its default value which is 0,0,0 causing your camera to move to some funky place.

Change: `

```
void start() {
...
}
```

to

```
void Start() {
...
}
```

Comment: Still same behavior, but this time the position of camera changes slower towards the ground.

Comment: Is your start function being run? The offset position seems fine to me.  I would debug the player position and the offset and see if they are correct.

Comment: Try changing start() to Start() in the camera script, if the camera is moving towards the ground then it seems like your offset isn't being set so remains at 0,0,0.

Comment: Changing it to Start() was the key. Thank you. Lerp seems behaving correctly after changing start to Start

Answer (score 0):

see you don't need any code for this just make you camera a child of your player object..

drag you camera object onto the player object in hierarchy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).